# Smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, differential-geometry

I am asked if there exists a smooth function

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

such that $f^{-1}(0)= \Delta$, where $\Delta$ represents the triangle with vertex $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$

I have noticed that $0$ can not be a regular value of $f$, but what about if zero is not a regular value?

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than it has to be. You can construct a smooth function that is zero only on the open triangle via standard real analysis. For example, construct a bump function $f$ that is $1$ on the triangle and has compact support, then take $g = 1-f$.

As to how to construct such a bump function $f$, consider the indicator function of $\Delta$ and take a convolution with a rescaled standard mollifier (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Concrete_example).